# Publish to Azure DevOps feed with same prerelease but different metadata?

Tags: git-flow, gitversion, azure-devops-artifacts, private-nuget-feed

We're trying to use GitVersion configured for GitFlow for some internal NuGet packages, published to an Azure DevOps feed.

A problem arises when we make commits to a release branch. They will be versioned like this by GitVersion:

```
0.3.0-rc.1+0 --> 0.3.0-rc.1+1 --> 0.3.0-rc.1+2 --> ...
```

In other words, the number of commits in the release branch is appended as build metadata in the FullSemVer string. We do get the package marked as this `FullSemVer` string, but the Azure DevOps feed rejects the packages with error "409 (Conflict - The feed already contains 'PackageName 0.3.0-rc.1+1'[...]". This happens even though the existing package has version "0.3.0-rc.1+0".

The behavior is correct with respect to how SemVer specifies version precedence, i.e. that build metadata should be ignored, so I suppose a solution would be to find a way to place the commit number in the prerelease part instead of in build metadata. But I can't seem to figure out how to achieve that using GitVersion.

Version like this would be acceptable:

```
0.3.0-rc.1.0 --> 0.3.0-rc.1.1 --> 0.3.0-rc.1.2 --> ...
```

Or like this (even better? seems to make sense to me):

```
0.3.0-rc.1 --> 0.3.0-rc.2 --> 0.3.0-rc.3 --> ...
```

How should I configure `gitversion.yml` to achieve that?

I'm kind of ruling out the alternative to get the feed to accept duplicates that only differ in the build metadata part, but if this option exists and would solve my problem I'm willing to consider it.

Here's our current `gitversion.yml`:

```yaml
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDelivery
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
tag-pre-release-weight: 60000
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: dev
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 0
  main:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    source-branches: [ 'develop', 'release' ]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: rc
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    source-branches: [ 'develop', 'main', 'support', 'release' ]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: feature-{BranchName}
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    source-branches: [ 'develop', 'main', 'release', 'feature', 'support', 'hotfix' ]    
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches: [ 'develop', 'main', 'release', 'feature', 'support', 'hotfix' ]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: rc
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches: [ 'develop', 'main', 'support' ]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    source-branches: [ 'main' ]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just realized that it seems to do the trick if I change mode for release to `ContinuousDeployment`. I guess I'll have to think through the best approach here, for all the branches.